# how does outbound-gateway handle json string from remote server

Tags: json, spring-integration

i'm new to spring integration, and i'm developing a proxy with it.

here is my configuration:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="testInboundGateway"
                          supported-methods="GET"
                          request-channel="test-request"
                          extract-reply-payload="false"
                          reply-channel="test-reply"
                          path="/user/{id}/info"
                          reply-timeout="50000">
    <int-http:header name="id" expression="#pathVariables.id"/>
</int-http:inbound-gateway>


<int-http:outbound-gateway id="testOutboundGateway"
                           http-method="GET"
                           request-channel="test-request"
                           reply-channel="test-process"
                           url="http://remoteserver/{id}.json"
                           extract-request-payload="false"
                           expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                           reply-timeout="50000"
                           charset="UTF-8">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="id" expression="headers.id" />
</int-http:outbound-gateway>

<int:service-activator id="activator"
                       input-channel="test-process"
                       output-channel="test-reply"
                       ref="hubBean"
                       method="process"></int:service-activator>

<bean id="hubBean" class="com.test.testhub.HubService"/>
```

My remote server returns JSON with content-type:application/json;charset=UTF-8

However my service bean get such String: \u001F \b\u0000\u0000.....

I don't know what it is.  I tried to decode it with gzip, but the format isn't correct.
so anyone can tell me how can i get the actual result?

Comment: Can you use a network sniffer (wireshark or eclipse's tcp/ip monitor etc) to take a look at the actual content?

Comment: Hi, the remote server returns neat json as i call it directly.  There must be something wrong with either encoding or converting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we already know that your response from that remote service is `gzipped`, even if it is JSON, there are two ways to overcome na issue and have robust solution:

1. Accepts response as `byte[]` (you do that now) and decompress manually.
2. Use `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` injection to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` with `DecompressingHttpClient` decorator reference.

I think the second one is better.

Answer (score 0):

It seem the problem is remote response is gzipped, and the String coverted is already wrong, so that I can't uncompress it.  I have to set the expected-response-type="byte[]" so that i can uncompress it by code.